# How I read Value from gpio in Background Task? C# Win IOT RP3

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, gpio, windows-10-iot-core, background-task

when I use BackgroundApp (IoT) template I get no values from the pins.
I try it exactly as in Foreground App, but there is no event triggered when pressing the button.
Can someone tell me what I do wrong?

Here is my Code

```
  namespace BackgroundApplication2
    {
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
    private const int LED_PIN = 6;
    private const int BUTTON_PIN = 5;
    private GpioPin ledPin;
    private GpioPin buttonPin;
    private GpioPinValue ledPinValue = GpioPinValue.High;

        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            InitGPIO();
          }

        private void InitGPIO()
        {
            var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

            if (gpio == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine( "There is no GPIO controller on this device.");
                return;
            }

            buttonPin = gpio.OpenPin(BUTTON_PIN);
            ledPin = gpio.OpenPin(LED_PIN);


            ledPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
            ledPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);


            if (buttonPin.IsDriveModeSupported(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp))
                buttonPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);
            else
                buttonPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);


            buttonPin.DebounceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);


            buttonPin.ValueChanged += buttonPin_ValueChanged;

            Debug.WriteLine("GPIO pins initialized correctly.");
        }

        private void buttonPin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {  

            if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
            {
                ledPinValue = (ledPinValue == GpioPinValue.Low) ?
                    GpioPinValue.High : GpioPinValue.Low;
                ledPin.Write(ledPinValue);
           }

       }

    }
    }
```

This Code works fine in a UWP-App

Answer (score 0):

This issue due to your BackgroundApp exits after executing `InitGPIO()` function. So you can't receive any events.

What you need is calling the "GetDeferral" method to prevent the application from exiting. You can do it like this:

```
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            InitGPIO();
        }
```

For more information about this behavior, you can reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications).